# What's Going to Happen to mi.yodeya?

Tags: discussion, pre-migration

According to the blog post at http://blog.stackexchange.com/post/518474918/stack-exchange-2-0, things are changing for all stackexchange sites. How will this affect mi.yodeya?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We shall see.

I have a guarantee from StackOverflow that I can keep operating mi.yodeya as I do now until at least April 2011 if I so choose. That gives up plenty of time to let options develop. We may decide to join the democratic StackExchance 2.0 model, we may migrate to one of the StackExchange clones, or we may try to stay with the StackExhange 1.0 model that we have now for as long as possible. When these options become more defined and I am at the point of seriously considering making a decision, I'll definitely seek community input.

The bottom line is that there won't be any major changes to the workings of this site very soon, and none any time without plenty of warning.

Comment: Great. Just making sure the site keeps up despite everything...